# No puedo actualizar el Modelo.edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Queria ver si alguien puede ayudarme con este problema:

Resulta que agregue una nueva tabla a mi BD y ahora quiero actualizar mi modelo.edmx, procedo a actualizarlo dando click derecho, actualizar y luego agrego la nueva tabla, esto me genera una clase de la nueva tabla, hasta ahi todo bien, pero en el context no me reconoce la nueva clase agregada, me marca el error "Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado", si alguien tiene una idea de que podria ser, le agradeceria mucho que me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: intentaste limpiar y volver a compilar el proyecto? el shortcurt `ctrl` + `.` qué te dice?

Comment: Si, intente todo eso, el shortcurt "ctrl + ." me da la opcion de agregar una clase nueva, pero esta clase ya se genera automaticamente en el model.tt, pero cuando intento llamar a esta clase no la reconoce, y solo me da el error "Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado".

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el problema, si a alguien mas le pasa algo similar, posiblemente sea un bug del VS studio, solo compila la solucion, en caso de que no te funcione haz como yo y cierra el proyecto y vuelve a abrirlo, asi se me soluciono el problema, gracias a los que intentaron ayudarme.

Answer (score -1):

Primero asegurate de crear la tabla en la DB, luego en la carpeta Modelos, abra el archivo .edmx para mostrar el diagrama del modelo. Haga clic con el botón derecho en cualquier lugar de la superficie de diseño
y seleccione Actualizar modelo desde la base de datos.

En el Asistente de actualización, seleccione la pestaña Actualizar y luego seleccione Tablas> dbo> que creaste . Haga clic en Finalizar.

Por lo que entiendo tu patron es DATABASE FIRST?

Comment: Si, mi patron es Database First, y ya he hecho todo lo que mencionas anteriormente, cuando se agrega la tabla en el modelo.edmx, se me crea la clase de la tabla en el model.tt, y tambien se me genera una clase "public virtual DbSet<Tabla_agregada> Tabla_agregada {get; set;}" en el model.context.cs, pero aqui se encuentra el problema, es que esta clase generada en el model.context.cs me dice "Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado" y la verdad he intentado de todo y hasta ahora no se que hacer.